# Flask-bcrypt, ValueError: Invalid salt

Tags: python, flask

```
File "/home/sergey/MyProject/flask_blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/sergey/MyProject/flask_blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/home/sergey/MyProject/flask_blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/home/sergey/MyProject/flask_blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "/home/sergey/MyProject/flask_blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/home/sergey/MyProject/flask_blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/home/sergey/MyProject/flask_blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/home/sergey/MyProject/flask_blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "/home/sergey/MyProject/flask_blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/home/sergey/MyProject/flask_blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/sergey/MyProject/flask_blog/app/views.py", line 46, in 
login
if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, 
form.password.data):
File "/home/sergey/MyProject/flask_blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/flask_bcrypt.py", line 193, in check_password_hash
return safe_str_cmp(bcrypt.hashpw(password, pw_hash), pw_hash)
File "/home/sergey/MyProject/flask_blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/bcrypt/__init__.py", line 87, in hashpw
raise ValueError("Invalid salt")
ValueError: Invalid salt
```

Дебаггер выводит такую ошибку, вот модель пользователей:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(100), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(128))
    role = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, default=ROLE_USER)
    posts = db.relationship('Entry', backref='users', lazy='dynamic', 
                    passive_deletes=True)  # ссылка на др. таблицу!!!
    about_me = db.Column(db.String(140))
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    avatar_hash = db.Column(db.String(32))
    authenticated = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    email_confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=True, 
                                            default=False)
    comment_user = db.relationship('Comment', backref='comment_user', 
                  lazy='dynamic') # связь пользователей и комментов
    support = db.relationship('Support', backref='support', 
                        lazy='dynamic')


    def __init__(self, nickname, email, password, about_me=None):
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.email = email
        self.about_me = about_me
        self.set_password(password)
        self.email_confirmed = False
        self.authenticated = False

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)


    def check_password(self, password):
        if bcrypt.check_password_hash(self.password, password):
            return True
```

Читал что проблема может быть связана с кодировкой, и ещё один важный момент, когда регистрирую пользователя всё проходит хорошо, когда снова захожу тоже получаю пароль, но когда хочу сбросить пароль, то потом появляется такая ошибка. Как решить эту проблему ?

Answer (score 0):

У меня 3.4, но вроде [тут](https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt/) нет отличий для версии, я так понимаю вы не генерируете `salt` для пароля, вывод `help(bcrypt)`:

```
FUNCTIONS
gensalt(rounds=12, prefix=b'2b')

hashpw(password, salt)
```

Вот я попробовал:

```
>>> a = bcrypt.gensalt(rounds=10)
>>> a
b'$2b$10$6axD5YapFa4JUtb.KTjDZu'
>>> b = hashpw('ololo', a)
>>> b
b'$2b$10$6axD5YapFa4JUtb.KTjDZulIOLKd5MUrry0xbl/gn/OA5gU6fnOgO'
>>> bcrypt.checkpw(b'ololo', b)
True
```

Comment: Я понял в чём дело, когда я пароль меняю, он не хэшируется, и записывается в базу данных как есть, то есть например 'ololo'.